# Excel online keeps changing my date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

So here is the problem, when I typed 08/03/2018 it changes automatically to 03/08/2018. Why? I set the number format for the whole column to date (Indonesian) dd/mm/yyyy.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Go to Online Region setting and change the Region as the same as your local regions settings. Refer to this support article: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-your-personal-language-and-region-settings-caa1fccc-bcdb-42f3-9e5b-45957647ffd7

Comment: @Lee You mean changing the region in onedrive? i cant do that, the account isnt mine

Comment: @AgilGA,, do this trick. Select the entire data range and apply **dd/mm/yyyy** forrmat.  Now,, while you type Date Value type **11/22/18 (i.e. Month/Date/Year)** Excel will convert the Date Value to **22/11/2018** and that's what you need.